# Does a -1/-1 effect from a static ability cause a creature to die before it can do anything, upon entering the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend has played [Engineered Plague](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Engineered%20Plague), naming *Elf*. Is the [Elvish Hexhunter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Hexhunter) of any use here? Imagine it has haste via [Concordant Crossroads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Concordant%20Crossroads).

Answer (score 12):

Your elf can't do anything. It becomes a 0/0 just after it enters the battlefield, and pretty much immediately goes to the graveyard. There's no opportunity to activate the ability before it dies. This has to do with *state-based actions*, and the fact that they're checked *before* you get priority:

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 116, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for
> state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions
> simultaneously as a single event.
>
> 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.

Triggered abilities, such as that of [Elvish Visionary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Visionary), will still trigger. You will place the ability onto the stack as soon as you get priority, which in this case is after the creature is already dead.

Comment: Enter The Battlefield effects would still trigger, no?

Comment: @EthanTheBrave Yes, it would.